# Trigger is not firing in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I've created the following trigger that should be looking for an update. My understanding is that an update creates an entry in the `DELETED` table and the `INSERTED` table. So I am unsure as to why the following isn't working. (It is checking to see if the value was changed from one to the other and if so, log it in a 2nd table).

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[captureNameChainToLocateComplete] 
ON [dbo].[tblLand]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @old AS varChar(50)
    DECLARE @new AS varChar(50)
    DECLARE @name AS varchar(50)
    DECLARE @now AS dateTime
    DECLARE @recordId AS varchar(50)

    SELECT @old = d.sSubdivision FROM DELETED d
    SELECT @new = i.sSubdivision FROM INSERTED i

    SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 sHistoryUser 
                    FROM tblDocumentHistory 
                    ORDER BY dtHistoryDate DESC)
    SELECT @recordId = (SELECT TOP 1 iRecordId 
                        FROM tblDocumentHistory 
                        ORDER BY dtHistoryDate DESC)
    SELECT @now = (SELECT GETDATE())

    IF @old = 'NAME CHAIN' AND @new = 'LOCATE COMPLETE'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO nameChainLog (recDate, irecordId, userName) 
        VALUES (@now, @recordId, @name)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO nameChainLog (recDate, irecordId, userName) 
        VALUES (@now, 'test', 'test')
    END
END
```

Edit: The second insert is just for troubleshooting to try to log when an else occurs.

Comment: Depending on how the update occurs (eg. a single row being updated, or multiples rows being updated), your DELETED and INSERTED tables may well contain multiple rows.  Therefore, you can't just set the value of a variable to a column from the DELETED or INSERTED tables - your variable will probably only get the value of the last row (or, to be honest, whichever row takes SQL Server's fancy).  If your UPDATE statement is affecting multiple rows (which it can), then your trigger needs to deal with the DELETED and INSERTED tables accordingly

Comment: In this case, the tblland table is only having one row updated, but also, checking 
`SELECT   d.object_id, 
         d.database_id, 
         DB_NAME(database_id) AS 'database_name',   
         OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) AS 'trigger_name', 
         d.last_execution_time
FROM     sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats AS d  
ORDER BY d.last_execution_time DESC;`

Doesn't show the trigger as ever even firing on an update from that tblland

Comment: Put some PRINTs in your trigger and test some updates to see what happens. It's impossible to say what's wrong from your post alone. As other said, as soon as you assign stuff to variables in trigger, you're probably on the path to failure, you gotta work with whole inserted/deleted block. Also, something wrong with the code formatting

Comment: Side note: Did you intend to swap `@name` and `@recordId` values in your second `nameChainLog` insert? The column list order does not match the value list order.

Comment: You should still, always, write your triggers to handle sets, not single rows, because there is nothing to stop you writing an SQL update statement which affects multiple rows.

Comment: [The Silent Bug](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: _In this case, the tblland table is only having one row updated_ You need to code for all cases. This is a bug waiting to happen. There are enough unintended bugs, don't uneccesarily introduce known ones. What is the purpose of this? It may be easier to just turn on SQL Server CDC or temporal tables. There's no code involved in that.

Comment: Checking on last_execution_time is not a safe way to see if the trigger is ever fired, it might have encountered an error (and from your code that is very very very likely) which might cause this data not being there as you would expect. Fix the errors in your trigger, the known errors are already been told to you, make it work with sets of data not with single variables, that is a bug. Then test again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try something like this, you need to cover the multiple updates

```
  CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[captureNameChainToLocateComplete] 
ON [dbo].[tblLand]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @old AS varChar(50)
    DECLARE @new AS varChar(50)
    DECLARE @name AS varchar(50)
    DECLARE @now AS dateTime
    DECLARE @recordId AS varchar(50)

    -- Use a cursor to handle multiple rows in DELETED and INSERTED
    DECLARE cursorTrigger CURSOR FOR
    SELECT d.sSubdivision, i.sSubdivision
    FROM DELETED d
    JOIN INSERTED i ON d.irecordId= i.irecordId

    OPEN cursorTrigger
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorTrigger INTO @old, @new

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @name = (SELECT TOP 1 sHistoryUser 
                        FROM tblDocumentHistory 
                        ORDER BY dtHistoryDate DESC)
        SELECT @recordId = (SELECT TOP 1 iRecordId 
                            FROM tblDocumentHistory 
                            ORDER BY dtHistoryDate DESC)
        SELECT @now = GETDATE()

        IF @old = 'NAME CHAIN' AND @new = 'LOCATE COMPLETE'
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO nameChainLog (recDate, irecordId, userName) 
            VALUES (@now, @recordId, @name)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO nameChainLog (recDate, irecordId, userName) 
            VALUES (@now, 'test', 'test')
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursorTrigger INTO @old, @new
    END

    CLOSE cursorTrigger
    DEALLOCATE cursorTrigger
END
```